# Zeppelin %python.conda and %python.sql interpreters do not work without adding Anaconda libraries to %PATH

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I have the following situation: I want to use Anaconda3 with Zeppelin and Spark.

I have installed the following components:

- HDP 2.5
- Spark 2.0.0.x (the version which comes with HDP 2.5)
- Zeppelin 0.7.3
- Anaconda3 with Python 3.5.4 (PySpark in Spark 2.0.0 and Python 3.6 are not friends)
- Python 2.7 comes with HDP 2.5 and is available in /usr/bin and this path is added to $PATH

Basically I configure the Python interpreter to point to my anaconda version, in my case /opt/anaconda3/bin/python and this is working. I also edited the zeppelin.sh script with:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${SPARK_HOME}/python:${SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip"
export SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV="PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/var/opt/teradata/anaconda3/envs/py35/bin/ipython"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/var/opt/teradata/anaconda3/envs/py35/bin/python"
export PYLIB="/var/opt/teradata/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib"
```

Till here everything is Ok.

When I try the **%python.conda** and **%python.sql** interpreters , they failed because the conda command is not found and the pandas also not.
I added the libraries location to the **$PATH** environment variable, and Zeppelin is able to find these commands but the side effect is, the default Python version for the whole environment becomes the **3.5** instead of the **2.7** and I start to get another nice error like this one:

```
apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException:   File "/usr/bin/hdp-select", line 205
    print "ERROR: Invalid package - " + name
                                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
ls: cannot access /usr/hdp//hadoop/lib: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: hdp.version is not set while running Spark under HDP, please set through HDP_VERSION in spark-env.sh or add a java-opts file in conf with -Dhdp.version=xxx
```

When I switch back and erase the Python3 libraries from $PATH it works again.

Is there any optimal way to configure my environment in order to make everything works and keep it manageable and easy to maintain?

I was thinking in creating symlinks in /var/lib for the files that need to be found, but I don’t know how many will be needed and I don’t want to create links for everyone except python3.

Any comment will be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards, Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same error.  Upon investigating, I tracked down the source of the error [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/python/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/python/PythonCondaInterpreter.java). Looks like Zeppelin is defaulting to "/bin/conda" for the default path for conda.

I was able to fix it by doing the following:

- Create a symlink to /bin/conda: `ln -s /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda /bin/conda`
- Create a symlink to /bin/python: `ln -s /opt/anaconda3/bin/python /bin/python`
- In the settings for the Python interpreter, set zeppelin.python to `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`
- Set the PYTHONPATH in /usr/lib/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh to `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin`

Looks like there is also a JIRA issue for this behavior [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2921).